# How to check in layout if user is logged in

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Like in title.
I have layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://bootswatch.com/4/journal/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <title>Node.js & Passport Login App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor03" aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Szukaj!</button>
          </form>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/index">Strona Główna
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nas</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%if (!isLoggedIn) { %>
              <div> <a class="nav-link" href="/users/logout">Wyloguj</a></div>
            <% } %>
              <%if (isLoggedIn) { %>
                <div> <a class="nav-link" href="/users/login">Zaloguj</a></div>

              <% } %>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container"><%- body %></div>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and some routes like e.g register view,where I check if user isLogged(no way to registration) etc.

```
router.get('/register', (req, res) =>
    res.render('register',{isLoggedIn:isLoggedIn()}));
```

I have 2 problems:

1)<%if> in my layout doesn't work (i don't know why)

2)How to inject state of user (logged or not) to layout? I don't want to repeat all of the code from layout on my views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem - thanks to @Fide for show me a way where is a bug!

```
router.get('/register',
    function (req,res){
    res.render('register', {user: req.User} )
    });
```

I have to take User from req - simple but I spent a lot of time on it!

Answer (score 2):

1. I think you have swapped the login/logout elements. For !isLoggedIn should be Zaloguj, for isLoggedIn should be Wyloguj.
   Generally, I attach to render some (not all, as it can contain pasword hashes) user data `res.render(‘register’, { user })` You will need them either, you will want to display logged in user name or so.
   Then:

```
    <% if (user) { %>
      <h2><%= user.name %></h2>
    <% } %>
```

2. If you have a part of ejs you want to have in other templates, just use includes:

```
<div id=“parent_div”>
  <div id=“register_div”>
    <% include('register.ejs') %>
  </div>
  <div id=“mainbody_div”>
    <% include('body.ejs') %>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: <%if(user) in layout still doesn't work :/ No, zaloguj and wyloguj are okay ;) If you are not logged you should have zaloguj for log in, and if you are logged you should have way to logout (wyloguj).

Comment: Can you add `<% console.log(“USER: “, user) ; if (user)....  %>` So you can see, what data you send to the template? 
True, if IsLoggedIn === true >> logout. I see, you have login.

Comment: ```
35|         <ul class="navbar-nav">
    36|           <li class="nav-item">
 >> 37|             <% console.log(user)%>
    38|             <%if (!user) { %>
    39|               <div> <a class="nav-link" href="/users/logout">Wyloguj</a></div>
    40|             <% } %>

user is not defined
````
It's not from console but from site.

Comment: This <%console.log()%> in in layout. And that layout is used on all of my views.

Comment: User is not defined? The render function does not pass user data to ejs template, is not the error on server?

Comment: I don't know how to check it. Everything looks ok.

Comment: Can you share here the path /register?

Comment: Thanks @Fide! I fixed my bug - answer below ;)